# ROS2: URL to camera_info yaml not being recognized

Tags: ros2, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running ROS2 dashing Ubuntu 18.04 bionic on x86.

URL to camera info yaml file not being recognized. The url is being loaded via the launch file as a parameter.

I have declared the parameter before trying to use.
I have confirmed that the intended url from the launch file is obtained.

See the following [repo](https://github.com/surfertas/ros2_ipcamera/issues). Place `camera_info.yaml` in the `/config` directory. (example file can be found [here](https://github.com/NVlabs/Deep_Object_Pose/blob/master/config/camera_info.yaml).)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333521/ros2:-url-to-camera_info-yaml-not-being-recognized/) by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 265 on 2019-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at your launch file, you need to either specify the `camera_calibration_file` with either a `file://` prefix or in the `package://` format.  Without the prefix on the URI, the package will fail to parse it.

Example correction:

```
# Using file://
config_file = 'file://' + os.path.join(config_dir, 'camera_info.yaml')
# OR using package://
config_file = 'package://ros2_ipcamera/config/camera_info.yaml'
```

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2019-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) on 2019-10-11**:
@mjcarroll Thank you for this. I went with using 'file://'.  Don't think I would have been able to figure this out without your input.